# Tkinter .focus_set() equivalent in PyQt4

Tags: python, cursor, pyqt, qlineedit

I have a `Qlineedit` widget which i will use to accept the username. It will be displayed as soon as user launch the application. I want the `Qlineedit` widget ready for typing (ie, with cursor already in place) without needing the user to use mouse to click on the widget before typing.

I have tried  `.setFocus()` and  `.setCursorPosition(1)` but doesn't seem to work.

Which method should i use to set the cursor at the starting position of `Qlineedit` without user needing to click on it?

Comment: setFocus works for me. Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake. I was trying to use `setFocus` before i add the widget to the layout.

Now, I used the `setFocus` method after the wiget is added to the layout and it works fine.